# Как в JavaFX создать таблицу содержащую изображения

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Как создать таблицу одно из полей которой может содержать изображение (ImageView)? Хотел использовать TableView, но прочитал что этот компонент используется для отображения текстовых данных. Для отображения вложенных компонентов надо использовать компонент GridPane. Таблица должна обновляться при изменении списка, т.е. должен быть скроллинг или paging.

Answer (score 3):

```
@FXML
private TableView<Pojo> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Pojo, ImageView> c4;
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    c4.setCellValueFactory(param2 -> {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView("file:D://123.png");
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>(imageView);
        });
}
```

Всё отображается